# nuxt-link: redirect to the same anchor with hash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxt-link

I'm using a `<nuxt-link>` component in my Nuxt application and I have the following problem:

- When I click for the first time on the link, everything works fine, if needed the page is changed and the anchor works perfectly
- However, if I scroll a bit on the page, and click the link again, nothing happens, because the url is already present in the browser navbar I assume.

How could I overwrite this behavior so that when I click on the `nuxt-link`, it scrolls to the desired section regardless of what I have clicked before ? (Without refreshing the page)

Here is what my `nuxt-link` looks like

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: localePath('/'), hash: '#homepage' }"
>
  <span>Homepage</span>
</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with this function bound to a `click.native` event as suggested by @Merc.

```
handleScroll(anchorId: string): void {
    if (this.$route.hash) {
      const anchor = document.querySelector(`#${anchorId}`)

      // Check if the anchor has been found
      if (anchor) {
        window.scrollTo({
          // Scroll so that the anchor is at the top of the view
          top: anchor.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should be able to add a click handler to your nuxt-link.

```
<nuxt-link
  :to="{ path: localePath('/'), hash: '#homepage' }"
  @click.native="scroll"
>
  Homepage
</nuxt-link>
```

(not sure about the `@click.native`, if that does not work just try `@click`)

And then within your methods:

```
methods: {
    scroll() {
      // your scroll function, probably reading document.documentElement.scrollTop or similar
    // if necessary check this.$route if the hash is already present, if so only do it in that case...
    },
}
```

Hope that gives you a point to start?!
Cheers